# C# Newsoft.Json Deserialize fails with nested "

Tags: c#, json, serialization, escaping

I'm acquiring some data from a web service via a HTTP request which looks like the following:

```
{
    ...
    "status" : "some_status",
    ...
}
```

Which is returned with characters escaped by `\` (i.e. `\"status\" : \"some_status\"`) and I am using [Newsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize the returned data as an (custom) object. The issue is, when `"some_status"` itself contains `"` like:

```
{
    ...
    "status" : "some_status "hello world"",
    ...
}
```

With again, each `"` escaped to `\"`, the deserialize fails with an `unexpected character`.

How can I specify using `Newsoft.Json` to ignore or remove the inner `"` completely? Or if it's impossible, maybe using `Regex`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it come unescaped in first place? You could change the inner double quotes to single quotes. I would say the json-string that you recieve is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JSON parser that will be able to deal with a JSON string that isn't properly formatted in the first place.

so you need to make sure that your theModel is formatted appropriately and according [JSON.org](http://json.org/) standards.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is incorrect. A string between double quotes can't contain others double quotes.
If it is useful you can test your JSON string with the online editor: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

You can't remove the double quotes otherwise your result is no more considered as a string but as an int.

I don't know how you are managing your webcall and having the backslash, but normally you should have something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://.....");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
object obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>`(reader.Read().ToString());
```

object is the type of the object you want deserialize to